# Logging from multiple workers in Gunicorn

Tags: python, logging, gunicorn

I'm working on a backend microservice, using the built in python logging library to monitor what is happening in my Flask app, and using Gunicorn to spin up multiple workers with it.

Ideally I would like to create a parent logger (`logging.GetLogger('Service')`), and each worker would use a child logger (`logging.GetLogger('Service.Worker1')`, `logging.GetLogger('Service.Worker2')`, etc.). However, I'm not sure if I have a way to differentiate worker processes.

Can I pass somehow different arguments for each new gunicorn worker?

Right now when I'm using the same logger in each worker (`logging.GetLogger('Service')` for all), I have no way to tell which worker created the log. This might not be an issue, but if I'm using a `logging.FileHandler` then separate processes may collide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround that I came up with is simply using `os.getpid()`, which will be unique in each worker. While this does the job and allows me to create unique names for logging, I'm still wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: I am stuck with that too. Running 4 workers and having 1 log file is not working. I noticed when log rotation happens only one worker will be able to write to the file.

Comment: @ParthPatel I ended up using a `SocketHandler`s in my workers, and a completely separate logging process. Inspired from here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network

I still needed the `os.getpid()` trick to be able to separate logs from different workers, using names like `MyService.1234`.